# Google App Engine -

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, jaxb, jax-rs, eclipse-juno

I'm struggling to get JAX-RS configured within Eclipse Juno for deployment to the Google App Engine, in fact, I haven't got as far as getting a local deployment to work (Jetty).

Here's the stack trace that I'm experiencing, but I don't understand why it's still having problems finding the class com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer, when I've included ALL jersey jar files (an overkill I know) and all JAXB JAR files (I'm not even getting that far to care yet!).

```
2012-11-25 22:22:50.622 java[5703:707] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Enabled
2012-11-25 22:22:50.623 java[5703:707] [Java CocoaComponent compatibility mode]: Setting timeout for SWT to 0.100000
Nov 25, 2012 10:22:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Nov 25, 2012 10:22:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed /Users/Rob/Development/HillingarIncidentReporting/HillingarGaeServer/war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Nov 25, 2012 10:22:51 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed /Users/Rob/Development/HillingarIncidentReporting/HillingarGaeServer/war/WEB-INF/web.xml
Nov 25, 2012 10:22:52 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:207)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:205)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
Nov 25, 2012 10:22:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:205)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)

Nov 25, 2012 10:22:52 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: failed Jersey Web Application: java.lang.NullPointerException
Nov 25, 2012 10:22:52 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
WARNING: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@798baf36{/,/Users/Rob/Development/HillingarIncidentReporting/HillingarGaeServer/war}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:205)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:249)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
Nov 25, 2012 10:22:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
Nov 25, 2012 10:22:52 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The admin console is running at http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin
2012-11-25 22:22:55.378 java[5703:6c03] Unable to obtain JNIEnv for context: 0x0
```

Here's a screenshot from all the JAR file specified in the Eclipse project - I'm assuming this is used by Jetty for local deployment?

[image: JARs referenced in Build Path - Configure Build Path]

Additionally, here's a copy of the SAME Jersey & JAXB jar files in the /war/WEB-INF/lib folder, as suggested in many other forums for when it's finally deployed in the Google App Engine

[image: Deployed war lib files]

**Question 1**
Primarily, I need to resolve why the JAR's aren't loading.  I have tried to change the order that they are loaded (I can only seem to do that in the Build Path - Configure Build Path), so here I set the jersey-servlet-1.15.jar file first (because it has the offending class present).

I've cleaned my project after each attempt to try and resolve this.  Does anyone know what I could be missing?

**Question 2**
Additionally, on a lower priority, I'm also wondering what Jersey and JAXB Jars are actually required, I suspect I only need a very small subset.  Perhaps all the jars are conflicting, although I have tried just having jersey-servley-1.15.jar and it still complained!

**Question 3**
I note that Jersey includes asm-3.1.jar - yet GAE already includes asm-4.0.jar, should I not include 3.1 as a newer version is already present?

**Question 4**
When I try to create a class that extends ServletContextListener, Eclipse does not offer 'ServletContextListener' in the list of classes, yet in the classpath I can clearly see that the 'App Engine SDK' version 1.7.3 includes servlet-api.jar and I suspect this is also included by default in Jetty at runtime.

Please, your help will be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add the servlet mapping in your web.xml? For example (using Spring, but should be similar):

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.evogro</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Q2: Your list matches mine (included via maven). I'm using jersey 1.13. I don't know if it is the minimum set you can get away with though

Q3: I have included ASM-3.3.1 as a dependency of datanucleus-enhancer. It is in the list of jars to be deployed. GAE will swap out any jars it doesn't like

Q4: ServletContextListener is an interface, which you implement. In the new class wizard, Eclipse should offer it to you in the add interfaces section.

I hope some of that solves some of your issues. I'm pretty new to this stuff!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Point 1 was a problem with compilation, not deployment, so I didn't need to add anything to web.xml to get that working.  In the end I created a fresh project, copied all the war files into the /war/WEB-INF/lib folder, then right-clicked on it and specified that I wanted them added to the project class path (as a reference / link).  This solved the compilation problem.

Comment: Point 4 - I'm used to NETbeans, I didn't really read the screen that differentiates between picking the superclass (that I stupidly selected) versus the 'add' button in the 'interfaces' section. Doh! Thanks, it works - I blame migrating from NB to Eclipse ;-)